React Native: how to get the orientation of an image
In React Native, given the path to an image file (.jpg) on the device, how can I get the orientation of that image?
Image.getSize() seems to always give the width as the smaller number, regardless of the actual orientation of the image.
I need a solution for Android and iOS.

I don't think there is another way, you have to compare height and width, which one is large you have to decide orientation.

But the smaller number is always assigned to "width" by Image.getSize(), whether the picture was taken portrait or landscape.  My point is, Image.getSize() is apparently unreliable for determining orientation.  Is there a way to reliably get the width and height?
